# How do I upload a screen shot to this page?

Tags: support, editing

I am having problems with setting up partitions after a new install 13.30. I think I have lost data. I have a screen shot of gparted but how do I upload it to this site so others can help me?

Comment: This will help you http://askubuntu.com/questions/417295/how-to-take-a-screenshot-and-then-upload-the-image-to-imgur-through-terminal

Comment: you need some reputation to upload the image to this site.So follow the above link and post the uploaded link back.Other high rep users may post the image on your question.

Answer (score 6):

> Adding a picture to a question or answer is now as easy as …
>
> 1. Clicking the Insert Image [image] toolbar button toolbar button
> 2. Selecting an image from your computer, or the web
> 3. Clicking Upload

[image]

**Note: you need to be registered member in the site with at least 10 reputation in order to [gain the privilege to use this feature](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/new-user).**

Source: [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75491/223264)

If you don't have at least 10 reputation, don't worry, you can [upload your image to imgur](https://askubuntu.com/q/417295/147044) for example and insert in the body question the link to the image. Someone who has enough reputation will most probably edit your question and will add the image correctly (of course, if the image is ok).

Comment: You might want to add a bit about uploading it to imgur and putting the link in the question if you don't have 10 reputation.

Comment: Also note you can use http://imgur.com/ conventionally, you don't have to do it from command line - but doing it from command line is great anyway :D